# Samsung ML-2850 Series Printer & Win 7 - Miscellaneous and Vague Errors

Tags: windows-7, printer, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer

I could bore you all to tears with an elaborate story of my hardships, but here's the deal:

- Small office (15 users)
- Windows 7 Professional
- Samsumg ML-2850 Series Printer
- Printer shared  on a server running Windows Server 2008 R2
- Situation only occurs on one user's machine
- All other printers work just dandy from user's machine, all of the time
- Every so often, the computer REFUSES to print until user reboots her computer. There is no error code, and the error message is different from program to program. Reinstalling the printer has done nothing at all to fix this.

I ran through everything and recorded my actions with the ever-fantastic Windows Problem Step Recorder (`psr.exe`) and have uploaded it to MediaFire:

[[Download]](http://www.mediafire.com/?e8bvzya0ylq4pxz)

Restarting the spooler service does nothing, either.

EDIT: Problem Step Recorder mysteriously decided to not take screenshots of some of the error messages, so here they are:

FileMaker Pro 9:
[image: FileMaker Pro 9]

FireFox:
[image: FireFox]

Outlook 2007:
[image: Outlook 2007]

Windows 7 Printer Test Page:
[image: Windows 7 Printer Test Page]

Comment: It could be anything from a bad Network Adapter or NA driver, bad cat 5 cable or wireless adapter or driver, we need more information on the hardware being used and if it is a Domain Server.

Comment: No idea how it could be bad equipment, as all other printers work just fine from that computer, and that printer works fine everywhere else. Windows Server 2008 R2 is not set up as a Domain Server.